# Is there a way to disable system(unix) caching for disk files?

Tags: c, unix, caching

I'm currently doing a performance test for b+tree vs. ordinary-balanced-tree on disk file operations(maybe a kind of dbms) in C. b+tree is expected to be faster than bbst because it performs fewer disk I/O operations. But I found that, after some testing, the system is doing caching for the disk files, the file was entirely saved in memory(my memory size is 32GB)! b+tree can by no means be faster than bbst because no disk I/O will be performed. So I wonder if there is a way to disable system caching so that b+tree will win in perf? I've tried open the file with O_DIRECT|O_SYNC:

```
int fd = Open("sb.dat", O_DIRECT|O_SYNC|O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
```

but it seems not work.

Here is some info provided by getrusage()

page reclaims: 1359821

page faults: 9

Comment: Why would you want to compare with caches off. It is what you'd get in real life. If you want to see how it performs with more tasks or more memory load, run some parallel benchmarks, or write a "memmuncher" application that allocates and then accesses that memory (in a loop - make sure however that you still have enough CPU capacity to run the system).

Comment: O_DIRECT|O_SYNC|O_CREAT|O_RDWR still didn't work:(

Comment: It's not easy to consume all of 32GB physical memory, and it's a server shared by all lab members, it's not very nice to do so..

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the kernel will still cache blocks from the disk even when you use `O_DIRECT`, you could drop the kernel cache but this only works the first time:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: @ClannChen you could call it before every I/O